# Avoiding Namespace Collisions with two classes that have the same name

Tags: c++

I have a 3rd party dll with classes. I want to have a class in my dll that will have the exact same name. How can I avoid a namespace collision?

What I would like to do is something like this:
My Program calls->My Dll calls->3rd Party dll

My dll and 3rd party dll both have a class with the same exact name.

1. List item

Comment: Put your class in a namespace different than the 3rd party uses.

Comment: I would like to keep the namespace the same. We are writing a replacement for a 3rd party library we are using, but for a period of time we would like to use both of them.

Comment: Classes with the same name and in the same namespace will collide.  Use a different class name or namespace until you're ready to drop the 3rd party dependency completely,  and then rename your stuff the way you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably do it like this:

```
namespace thirdPartyDLL {

    class A {
    public:
       A() {}
       void someFunc() {
       }
    };
} 
namespace yourDLL {

    class A {

        thirdPartyDLL::A a;

    public:
        A() {}
        void someFunc() {a.someFunc();}
    };
}
```

Maybe an ugly solution but this way both classes can have the same name.